# "A Rule That ...." Structure

Tags: relative-pronouns, reported-speech

I understand the structures "a rumor that...", "a comment that ...", "a though that....", etc.

But I don't get this sentence:

> For some interviews, there is ***a rule that reporters must not disclose sensitive information***.

Is "*a rule that....*" wrong?

If "*a rule that...*" is good English, would "*a regulation that....*" or "*a law that...*" work too?

Answer (score 2):

Meatie, you should learn how to use the [COCA corpus](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/). Here are a few examples of **a rule that** that I found. There are many more.

> FDR would have his cocktail hour, where he had **a rule that** you could only talk about movies and gossip.
>
> Mr. de Klerk was still holding out for **a rule that** the president could be overruled by his coalition cabinet.
>
> they should put a time limit between pitches, and enforce **a rule that** batters are not allowed to keep stepping out of the batter's box.
>
> At Harvard we have **a rule that** you can not impose more than 60 days of secrecy under a research contract

Yes, **a regulation that** and **a law that** are fine. You can do the search yourself for those.

Comment: Would adding "that says" be better?  "a rule/law/regulation ***that says*** that ...."

Comment: @meatie, you could certainly write it that way if you like, but to me it seems unnecessary.